# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k}k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

How can I evaulate the following series?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k}k$$

I don't know where to begin. $2^k$ alone would be straight forward.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms

Comment: Hint: Consider $S(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x^k$ and derivate with respect to $x$ once. What do you get?//(You are looking for $xS'(2))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^nk2^k=\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{k=m}^n2^k$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: He says in his question that he knows how to do geometric sums.

Comment: They said $2^k$ alone would be straight forward

Answer (score 1):

Call $a_n$ the expression you want to get. 
First, we have $$a_{n+1}=a_n+2^{n+1}(n+1)$$

Second, we have 
$2a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k+1}k$. So, 
$$2a_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k+1}(k+1)=a_{n+1}-2$$
So, $2a_n+2^{n+2}-4=a_{n+1}-2$. Hence
$$2a_{n}+2^{n+2}-2=a_{n+1}$$

We have two linear equations with the variables $a_{n+1}$,$a_n$. Solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove by induction that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k\cdot k=2\left(1+2^n(n-1)\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k} = infinity$$

then your sum is greater so it to goes to infinity

The comparison test shows why.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-6/v/comparison-test-convergence

Comment: Is a finite sum, not an infinite sum.